# How does return work (why is this not working)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not sure why this doesn't work, I also tried returning True/False and using elif and else:

```
def player_input():
    print("Rock, Paper, or Scissors", end="")
    return input(": ")


def check_input():
    if player_input() == "rock":
        return 1
    if player_input() == "paper":
        return 1
    if player_input() == "scissors":
        return 1


while check_input() != 1:
    player_input()
```

Comment: _How does return work_ I’m sure you can easily find tons of answers to that question, have you done any research?

Answer (score 0):

In `check_input()` in each `if` you are calling `player_input()` - better is to call it once and store the result value.

For example:

```
def player_input():
    print("Rock, Paper, or Scissors", end="")
    return input(": ")

def check_input():
    val = player_input()
    return val in ("rock", "paper", "scissors")

while check_input() != True:
    player_input()
```

Comment: what does the "in" do exactly? I've only used it for "in range(0, 3)" in for loops.

Comment: @HunterPace The `in` operator is used to check if a value exists in a sequence or not. Evaluates to `True` if it finds a variable in the specified sequence and `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new too, but if you need to repeat when the input is rock, paper, scissors:

```
while True:
    y = input("Rock, Paper, or Scissors: ")
    if y != "rock" or y != "paper" or y != "scissors":
        break
```

If you want to end the program when the input is rock, paper, scissors:

```
while True:
    y = input("Rock, Paper, or Scissors: ")
    if y == "rock" or y == "paper" or y == "scissors":
        break
```

I hope it helped!

Comment: Instead of the `while x == 0:` technique, just use `while True:` and `break`.